# What is the difference about two sentences below?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, nouns, sentence

What is the difference about two sentences below?

1.Despite a very old medical therapy, acupuncture is called "new age" treatment.

2.Despite being a very old medical therapy, acupuncture is called "new age" treatment.

and is number1 incorrect?

Comment: What's the difference between "Despite a broken leg, he managed to finish the race"  AND  "Despite being a broken leg, he managed to finish the race."

Comment: This almost seems trivial. If acupuncture were called "new age" treatment, in site of a very old medical therapy, then (1) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that the first sentence, at least at first reading, does not make any sense.

> 2.Despite being a very old medical therapy, acupuncture is called "new age" treatment.

This sentence makes sense:

> Even though it **is** a very old therapy, it is called "new age".

The first version:

> 1.Despite a very old medical therapy, acupuncture is called "new age" treatment.

I would parse as:

> Even though an old treatment exists, acupuncture is called new age.

So, for example, even though praying exists, we call acupuncture "new age". This does not make much sense.